# JQuery Dialog('open') not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/mUpjw/15/

I had JQuery 1.2 in some old code and it was opening dialog this way.

```
$('#myDiv').dialog('open');
```

I upgraded to jquery 1.6.1 and it was working fine . But if I add a DOCTYPE than it doesnt work but if I do

```
$('#myDiv').dialog();
```

That works fine.

What can be reason for this ?

Comment: @AlienWebguy http://jsfiddle.net/mUpjw/15/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup your dialog box.

```
<div id="dialog_link">click here</div>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">This is some document here.Will be shown as used 'open'</div>
<div id="mydiv2" style="display:none;">This is some document here</div>

$(document).ready( function(){

$('#mydiv').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$('#dialog_link').click(function() {
    $('#mydiv').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: interesting fact is that when $('#mydiv').dialog({..}) was outside of .ready() it did not open. As I moved it inside everything started working as expected. Go figure.
Thanks @Caimen

Answer (score 0):

This is an option to be used **after** you have initialized the dialog..

```
$('#mydiv').dialog({autoOpen: false});
// now you can call it with 'open' to actually show it..
$('#myDiv').dialog('open');
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mUpjw/16/

The difference is between the *jQuery UI* versions and not the *jQuery library*

Comment: I had the same issue, This answer solved my issue. thanks